# google-bigquery: Data Size of the data which query is going to process

Tags: google-bigquery

When enter the query in BigQuery text box ,it immediately provide the size of the data which the query going to process for e.g This query will process 839 GB when run.

Question 1: How bigquery knows so fast about the data size its going to process.

Question 2: How accurate is this figure

Question 3: I want to get this figure through bigquery tool and want to use in my project . Is there a way to get this figure through API.

Answer (score 4):

1. BigQuery looks at all the columns mentioned in your query, and adds their size. That's the total data to be processed: It only counts the columns mentioned, and their full size.
2. 100% accurate, as long as the column size doesn't change in the meantime.
3. API parameter to access this figure: dryRun. It doesn't use quota, so feel free to query. https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding question 3 , I am trying to access bigquery through post request but couldn't though I am able to access through Big Query from command line tool. Post Request.    https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{project-ID}/queries?key={key for browser apps}&query={query} . The response i am getting is "Not Found" ,is I am doing anything wrong. Please help . Moreover How can I get "dryRun" parameter through bigquery command line tool

Comment: Is there way to get dryRun parameter through bigquery command line tool

Comment: bq help query ->  bq query --dry_run